# run-time error 424 while checking change events

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a program which looks for items in Column A or Column I to change. If column I changes, it deletes and moves the row to a new sheet. If Column A changes, it should sort all of the data. However, when the second `Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address))` is called, it errors out telling me I have a run-time error 424. Why is this happening? It seems to have both a key cells range and a target.address.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim KeyCells2 As Range
    Dim LastRowCompleted As Long
    Dim RowToDelete As Long
    Dim CurCell As String
    RowToDelete = 0
    LastRow = Sheets("Current").Cells(Sheets("Current").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowCompleted = Sheets("completed").Cells(Sheets("completed").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowCompleted = LastRowCompleted + 1 'Next row after last row
    Set KeyCells = Range("I3:I16384")
    Set KeyCells2 = Range("A3:A16384")
    CurCell = ActiveCell.Address

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Cut and Paste Row
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("completed").Range(LastRowCompleted & ":" & LastRowCompleted)
        'Mark to delete row
        RowToDelete = Target.EntireRow.Row

        Call DeleteRow(RowToDelete)

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    Range(CurCell).Select

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

                'Sort
MsgBox "lastrow completed: " & LastRow
        Range("A3:Z" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("current").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("current").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("current").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("current").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("current").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A3:J" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range(CurCell).Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteRow(Row As Long)
    If Row > 0 Then
        Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If Not Intersect(KeyCells2, Target) Is Nothing Then` instead. Also, you can change `Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp` to `Rows(Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: @ShaiRado that doesn't seem to help. I still obtain the same error. I have a feeling `Range(Target.Address)` is not getting the value is should some how.

Comment: you don't need to use `Range(Target.Address)` since `Target` is already defined as `Range`

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the row in the first `If` block then `Target` no longer exists, so you can't use it in your second `If` block.

As a fix you could exit the Sub after deleting the row.

P.S. - that "auto-sort" seems like it would be pretty annoying if you're trying to edit data...